# print the line which is satisfying my condition and also the line next to it - awk

Tags: unix, awk, text-processing, gawk

```
tail -3000 ${file}.* | awk -vstart="${logStartTime}" -vend="${logEndTime}" \
  -vdate="${logDate}" '$1 == date && $2 > start && $2 < end {p=1} \
  $1 == date && $2 > end {p=0} p == 1 {print}'
```

Currently I could print the which is satisfying the condition, but I want to print the line which is satisfying my condition and also the line next to it.

Comment: What does `next to it` mean? Before it or after it or both or something else? Edit your question to show some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplfied a bit:

```
tail -3000 ${file}.* | awk -vstart="${logStartTime}" -vend="${logEndTime}" \
  -vdate="${logDate}" '$1 == date && $2 > start && $2 < end {print; getline; print}'
```

The `print` in after the condition, just prints the line (no need to set a variable and check it later). With `getline` awk reads the next line into it's buffer, and `print` again to print that line.

Comment: That would print the matching line twice if it occurred at the end of the file and has all of the other common getline caveats. If you're ever considering using getline make sure you read and fully understand http://awk.info/?tip/getline first (and then you wouldn't use it for something like this).

Answer (score 0):

This awk idiom will do

```
awk '/pattern/||!(n=!n)'
```

print if matches pattern or n is not set, which will be flipped back after evaluation of that premise.

In your case replace `/pattern/` with your condition